# Stringformat a MultiIndex DatetimeIndex using Babel's format_datetime() for Localization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, python-babel

- Python 3.7.0
- pandas 1.1.5
- numpy 1.21.4
- Babel 2.9.1

## Problem

I have a dataset that is first evaluated, then completed with calculations and then converted into a `pd.MultiIndex` by grouping it with the `pd.Grouper`. The result looks something like this:

```
                           delta (secs)
identifier   start_dt          
FOO          '2021-11-30'  10738.823
BAR          '2021-11-30'    116.000
```

And the index looks like this:

```
MultiIndex([('FOO', '2021-11-30'),
            ('BAR', '2021-11-30')],
           names=['identifier', 'start_dt'])
```

For better readability, I want to use Babel to properly localize the datetime output in the index columns according to a the locale.

When I try to apply Babel's `format_datetime()` function to the `DateTimeIndex` like so:

```
mi_frame.index = mi_frame.index.set_levels(
    format_datetime(
        mi_frame.index,
        format=time_format,
        tzinfo=get_timezone('Europe/Berlin'),
        locale="de_DE"),
    level=1)
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'`. Other methods such as `.apply()` returned the same error.

The problem lies in the `MultiIndex`'s `Index` data type (`DateTimeIndex`), that only allows its own string manipulation / representation method `.strftime(time_format)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer on type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52853671) by [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002) from a `DateTimeIndex` to a Python `datetime` object, one can pipe it into Babel's functions as they expect a native Python datetime object.

So the solution to my problem is not very elegant, but it works:

- Cast the DatetimeIndex to a a numpy array of datetime objects
- Cast to a list to perform a list comprehension
- Use Babel's `format_datetime()` to convert the datetime objects into the desired string representations
- re-assign the list to the MultiIndex index at the previous level (here: `level=1`) using pandas' `MultiIndex.index.set_levels()`

```
dt_array = list(mi_frame.index.levels[1].to_pydatetime())

dt_array = [format_datetime(idx, format="MMM", tzinfo=get_timezone('Europe/Berlin'), locale="de_DE")
            for idx in dt_array]
mi_frame.index = mi_frame.index.set_levels(dt_array, level=1)
```

Which yields (after some arithmetic added):

```
                             delta  percentage
identifier   start_dt                       
FOO          Nov.        10738.823         0.4
BAR          Nov.          116.000         0.0
```

The `Nov.` results according to the `"MMM"` format string described in [the official Babel documentation](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html).